# How to check if first column of a file equals a value

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using `awk '{if((echo $1 | cut -c1-3 align_1.da) eq "chr") print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' align_1.da > align_1.dat` to see if the 1st column of every line in the align_1.da file is equal to "chr" and if it is to put that in align_1.dat. However, I am getting a syntax error, can one of yall help?

Input format:

```
          chr11 75781924 0 chr5 98293255 16

          asi:3 4454545  2 asi:5. 643356 16

          chr8 8201901 0 chr11 80828426 16
```

Error:

```
           awk: cmd. line:1: {if((echo $1 | cut -c1-3 align_1.da) eq "chr") 
           print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}
           awk: cmd. line:1:                ^ syntax error
           awk: cmd. line:1: {if((echo $1 | cut -c1-3 align_1.da) eq "chr") 
           print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}
           awk: cmd. line:1:                                 ^ syntax error
           awk: cmd. line:1: {if((echo $1 | cut -c1-3 align_1.da) eq "chr") 
           print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}
           awk: cmd. line:1:                                      ^ syntax error
           awk: cmd. line:1: {if((echo $1 | cut -c1-3 align_1.da) eq "chr") 
           print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}
           awk: cmd. line:1:                                                ^ syntax error
           awk: cmd. line:1: {if((echo $1 | cut -c1-3 align_1.da) eq "chr") 
           print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}
           awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                      ^ syntax error
```

Comment: Include sample input, sample output, error, or you'll get more downvotes and less answers.

Comment: Okay added image of error

Comment: wrong. Write code, don't link images. How could we copy code or errors if for some reason we want to compare it with something else? Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Okay added it to the image.

Comment: I have found a recursive solution, but I am wondering if there is a method that can directly check this without going through each row(because the files I am working with have, on average, 100 million lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the output from cut inside an awk script.  Awk is an interpreted scripting language which will read your script and then run in its own process, and `cut` is a another program entirely separate from awk.  There are ways of using the output of outside processes from inside awk, but it is unnecessary in this case since we can use the substr() function to do the exact same thing cut would:

```
awk '(substr($1, 1, 3) == "chr") {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' align_1.da  > align_1.dat
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! Didn't know bash had a substr func.

Comment: It is actually awk that has the substr() function.  Everything between the single quotes is awk scripting.  Everything outside is bash, so really we're only using bash to run awk and then redirect the output from awk to the new file.

Comment: Oh okay, do you know if =~ is supported in awk?

Comment: =~ as in "matches regular expression" in other languages is just ~ in awk, so you would write something like '($1 ~ /[0-9]+/) {print}' to get all the records where the first column contains a number.